# Set module in configuration

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to open a sample Android [project](https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid2ndEdition/tree/master/chapter12/BitsandPizzas) in Android Studio. 
The project opens but I can't compile and run it on my emulators.

[image]

I tried to add configuration but I can't select module:

[image]

Why is this happening? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: try adding module manually in **setting gradle**?

Answer (score 0):

-follwing files are missing in project
/.idea/BitsandPizzas.iml
/app/app.iml
-once you fresh open project android studio will ask to remove following two module (app and BitsandPizzas) you have keep modules.
-and built project agian.
-it worked for me.